# How can one set up Kubernetes DNS using an IP address that is not host specific to the Kubernetes API?

Tags: kubernetes, skydns, kube-dns

I am having a difficult time finding out how one would get Kubernetes DNS (skydns, now called kube-dns) such that the kube-dns container/pod knows how to connect to the API server using an IP address or host that will work regardless if a master node goes down and another API server is started on a host with a different IP address?

I have tried using the actual Kubernetes service, but it runs on port 443 and the kube-dns (and formerly kube2sky) cannot connect to it.

Is there a more straightforward way other than having a mechanism to delete and recreate the kube-dns pod?

Comment: and by "re-create the kube-dns pod", I meant, restarting the pod when the API server changes it's IP because a host went down and it was brought up elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can query for `endpoint` and directly look for the one that corresponds to `kubernetes`. I can get it in two ways. One is directly query for endpoints:

```
$ kubectl get ep
NAME         ENDPOINTS              AGE
kubernetes   192.168.122.116:8443   15h
```

Or describe the service `kubernetes` running in the `default` namespace:

```
$ kubectl describe svc kubernetes
Name:                   kubernetes
Namespace:              default
Labels:                 component=apiserver
                        provider=kubernetes
Annotations:            <none>
Selector:               <none>
Type:                   ClusterIP
IP:                     10.0.0.1
Port:                   https   443/TCP
Endpoints:              192.168.122.116:8443
Session Affinity:       ClientIP
Events:                 <none>
```

Here I get the host IP address and port and it is not running on 443; it's 8443. See if this helps solve your problem.

Or try adding one more port to `kubernetes` service whose target port is the same.

Answer (score 0):

> how one would get kubernetes DNS (skydns, now called kube-dns) such that the kube-dns container/pod knows how to connect to the API server using and IP address or host

I don't think kube-dns needs to connect to APIServer in Kubernetes' design.

But if you are trying to find a stable way to connect to APIServer (like you said "regardless if a master node goes down and another API server is started on a host with a different IP address"), you've already done this if you deploy your cluster using `kubeadm` ([more information about kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/kubeadm/#manage-tokens)). And this is implemented through the Kubernetes service. You can check that like this:

```
$ kubelet describe svc kubernetes
Name:                   kubernetes
Namespace:              default
Labels:                 component=apiserver
                        provider=kubernetes
Selector:               <none>
Type:                   ClusterIP
IP:                     10.96.0.1
Port:                   https   443/TCP
Endpoints:              10.140.0.2:6443
Session Affinity:       ClientIP
No events.
```

You can access APIServer through either 10.96.0.1:443 (which is ClusterIP) or 10.140.0.2:6443 (which is the pod IP address of the APIServer pod) through:

```
$ curl https://10.140.0.2:6443/version --cert /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.pem --key /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-key.pem --cacert /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.pem
{
  "major": "1",
  "minor": "5",
  "gitVersion": "v1.5.4",
  "gitCommit": "7243c69eb523aa4377bce883e7c0dd76b84709a1",
  "gitTreeState": "clean",
  "buildDate": "2017-03-07T23:34:32Z",
  "goVersion": "go1.7.4",
  "compiler": "gc",
  "platform": "linux/amd64"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

`kubelet describe svc kubernetes`